# Add every item of an Array to mysql db

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm pretty new to Java Script and tried to write a small programm to add users to a database. My problem is, that my programs doesn't add every user ones. It adds the last user as often as there are users in the list. users has more than 2 Objects and all the Objects have all field filled.

```
    for(i = 0; i<users.length; i++)
{

    var user = users[i];
    console.log(user.lastonline)
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if (err) throw err;
    var quer = connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET `steamid` = '+ connection.escape(user.steamid)+', `name`='+connection.escape(user.name)+', `lastonline`='+connection.escape(user.lastonline)+' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `name`='+connection.escape(user.name)+', `lastonline`='+connection.escape(user.lastonline)+'', function(err, result) {
    connection.release();
    });
    console.log(quer.sql);
    });
}
```

I tried to rewrite this in a lot of different way, but most time I get something like this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'steamid' of undefined

```
    for(i = 0; i<users.length; i++)
{


    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        console.log(users[i]["steamid"]);
        if (err) throw err;
    var quer = connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET `steamid` = '+ connection.escape(users[i]["steamid"])+', `name`='+connection.escape(users[i].name)+', `lastonline`='+connection.escape(users[i].lastonline)+' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `name`='+connection.escape(users[i].name)+', `lastonline`='+connection.escape(users[i].lastonline)+'', function(err, result) {
    connection.release();
    });
    console.log(quer.sql);
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Rest of the programm

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'localhost',
  user            : 'zar',
  password        : 'qxLLPa06iEs2Bzsu',
  database        : 'zar',
  socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});

pool.on('connection', function (connection) {
  console.log("connection made")
});
//my testing users
var users = [];
times = Date.now();
user1 = {steamid:012345678912345658,name:"user1",lastonline:times};
user2 = {steamid:012345678912345628,name:"user2",lastonline:times};
user3 = {steamid:012345678912345618,name:"user3",lastonline:times};
users.push(user1);
users.push(user2);
users.push(user3);
```

Comment: Keep log for `users` before your `for` loop

Comment: The log was only for testing there, if I remove it, I get the same error but 2 lines later.

Comment: I'm asking to check whether your `users` list really have `objects` in it.

Comment: I do this before the code, that I've posted here. 'users' has at least more than 2 Objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Fixed to use only one connection.

Previous version was getting a new connection for every user.

You should use Promises:

```
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    var tasks = users.map((user) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } 

            var quer = connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET `steamid` = ' + connection.escape(user.steamid) + ', `name`=' + connection.escape(user.name) + ', `lastonline`=' + connection.escape(user.lastonline) + ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `name`=' + connection.escape(users.name) + ', `lastonline`=' + connection.escape(users.lastonline) + '', function (err, result) {                
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(result);
            });            
        });
    });


    Promise.all(tasks)
    .then((results) => {
        // Array of results passed in resolve
        connection.release();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // All errors you reject are catched here      
    });
});
```

This should workd but still, you are executing all queries in parallel, which can be pretty aggressive for the DB.

I suggest you to look into [bluebird Promise.each](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) for better results.

Comment: This works half. It shows all the querys now but on my database only the last user is added. I wouldn't think that 3 objects once are to much for the db. any clues why?

Comment: Tried it with Promise.each too and get the same result. The right querries are shown but I only get the last one in my db.

Comment: 1. The }); before the promise block need to be removed, else you have one to much, if you don't want to close the function. 2.  I had to remove `connection.release();`, because the on connection shouldn't be closed. But now only the first user ist added to the db.

Comment: You're right, corrected. Sorry but it's hard to guess what the problem is if i can't run your code. Maybe the problem is related to the package you use for MYSQL. Anyway you should definitely use promises when dealing with async code like db queries.

Comment: Yeah, I have learned, that I should use Promises. Read a lot about them again this evening. I added the rest of my test program, which I use atm, to figure out the error . When I use your part only user1 is added to the db. If I use mine, only user3.
PS: My db is a mysqldb with only the fields 'steamid', 'name' and 'timestamp'